# Multiple operator overloads results in ambiguous call

Tags: c++

I get an error when implementing multiple operator == like so:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(int data, int data_b) { m_data = data;}
    operator int() { return static_cast<int> (m_data);}
    operator float() { return static_cast<float> (m_data);}
private:
    char m_data;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MyClass myClass(4, 6);

    float aFloat= 5.4F;
    if(myClass == aFloat)
    {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

this is the error I get:

> 1>: error C2593: 'operator ==' is ambiguous 1>          could be
>   'built-in C++ operator==(int, float)' 1>          or       'built-in
>   C++ operator==(float, float)' 1>          while trying to match the
>   argument list '(MyClass, float)'

What's going on here? Shouldn't the compile figure out it should use the float overload?

Comment: "Shouldn't the compile figure out it should use the float overload?" -- Based on what? If there's an `f(int, float)` and an `f(float, float)` function overload, and you call `f(myClass, 5.4F)`, that would clearly be ambiguous. Can you explain why it should be different with `operator==`?

Comment: I think its the fact the operator == gets two parameters that confuses me. Why doesn't the error say 'could be operator(float) or operator(int)?

Comment: Remember that `a==b` gets treated for purposes of overload resolution as `operator==(a,b)` here. It has two arguments because `==` is a binary operator. It just so happens that the RHS (`aFloat`) doesn't need any conversion for either of those two alternatives.

Comment: And it's not the class operator== that gets called, but like the error says, 'built in C++ operator==()'. It's getting clear for me now, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't *explicitly* overloaded the `==` operator, the compiler looks at your class and tries to extract alternatives from it. and it found them :

1)it can convert your class to `int`, then compare
2)it can covert your class to `float`,then compare

since both makes the same sense to the compiler, it can't decide and prevent the code from compiling.

you can fix it by explicitly overloading `==` operator.

EDIT:
one thing that many C++ developers miss is that the compiler can't do *2* implicit convertions on their code. it can do only one. there are nomurous questions regarding to this "implicit convert twice" problem.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!

Comment: you welcome, and always remember, C++ *is* the truth.

Answer (score 0):

The call is ambiguous because a `MyClass` object can be implicitly converted to both `int` and `float` and there exist both overloads for `operator==`. One way to solve this is to disambiguate with a `static_cast` for example:

```
if(static_cast<float>(myClass) == aFloat) {
    ...
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6154226f83292610)

Answer (score 0):

No. The compiler knows that it can either compare `int` and `float` or `float` and `float`. It doesn't have a preference.

Your class provides conversions to both so the compiler isn't sure which behaviour you expect.

You need to be more specific: `if ((float)myClass == aFloat)`